# Windows Phone development

Tags: windows-phone, voip

I want to develop a softphone application for Mobile Phone platform (Mobile phones using Windows Mobile 7.1 or Higher) that is independent from the PBX, so that it can works with Asterisk, Askozia , 3CX, and any other kind of VoIP PBX, without the need to put other software inside and/or PBX. I know that this kind of applications exists, since I used it on other platforms, like 3CX client or BRIA client, both for iOS. I have all Microsoft tools and sdk needed to build that kind of applications, correctly configured and working. I already built other apps for Mobile Phone platform.

I had found a free trial version of Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK and I downloaded the latest version of the library from http://voip-sip-sdk.com/p_21-download-ozeki-voip-sip-sdk-voip.html and installed it. While I was easily able to build the sample softphone projects, I didn't understand how to build a softphone for mobile phones. Since I saw that softphone related class are in VoIPSDK.dll, I also tried to add reference to VoIPSDK.dll in Windows Phone Project, but Visual Studio gives an error complaining about "unsupported library".
So, what I need to now, since this is our main purpose, is it possible with this library to build a softphone for mobile platforms? In case, may I have a sample or the instruction on how to use Ozeki SDK library on these platforms? Maybe, I should create another application (the mediagateway) that should sit between the pbx and the mobile phone app. Have you got any experience with this library and mobile applications?

Comment: Is this a real question?  If so I suggest you add some code examples and be precise and show any errors you are getting.